# R: Multiple levels of grouping in dplyr::summarise using lapply

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lapply

I'm relatively new to R and I seem to be having trouble applying a list criteria to a data.frame I'm trying to summarize. I've been reading a bunch of different posts, but they only seem to be concerned with one level of grouping, and not a second one.

Assuming my df looks like this (my actual data frame is much larger. There are 35 different "Codes" and about 20 different "Colors")

```
    Code   Color   Value
[1] A      Red     10
[2] A      Blue    15
[3] A      Red     5
[4] B      Green   20
[5] B      Red     15 
[6] C      Green   10
```

Ideally, I'd like to create a summary table which enables me to group the data by Code (I've been successful doing this with Group by and Split) but then i'd also like to create a sum of values by criteria "Color". Currently, I've only been able to accomplish this by running the criteria one by one.

So far I've been able to do this:

```
#this gives me the total value by each code, like a pivot or a sumif
dfsummary <-df %>% group_by(Code) %>% summarise (total = sum(Value))

#then I was able to come up with this to give me, by Code, value by Color.
dfsummary2 <- df %>% filter(Color == "Red") %>% group_by(Code) 
%>% summarise(sumRed = sum(Value))
```

The results in dfsummary2 are:

```
   Code   sumRed   
[1] A      15     
[2] B      15    
[3] C      0
```

What I'd like to accomplish is creating a data frame for all "Color" without having to specify each one individually.

My desired output, let's call it dfsummaryall, looks like:

```
    Code   sumRed   sumBlue  sumGreen
[1] A      15       15       0
[2] B      15       0        20
[3] C      0        0        10
```

This is where I get stumped. I can run each one individually and then merge them into one table, but I'd like to find a way to work in an apply function (lapply, I would think). This is where I'm definitely a novice.

My attempt so far, and this is where I'm sure I'm egregiously wrong, goes like this:

```
colors <- c("Red","Blue","Green")

dfsummaryall <- lapply(colors, function(x){dftmp <- df %>%
dplyr::filter(Color == x) %>% group_by(Code) %>% 
summarise(x == sum(MktValue)
```

I know there's definitely a problem here in the "summarise(x == sum(MktValue)" part, but I'm really stumped as to how to pull this off.

Any help would be truly appreciated!

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Code, Color) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(Value)) %>% tidyr::spread(Color, Sum, fill = 0)`?

Comment: I see that i was going about things the wrong way. Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I suppose it never occurred to me that group_by could accommodate multiple levels.

Comment: In continuation of that: how could you handle then extracting sums for different code combinations. Say you want to go from dfsummaryall and see the sums of all columns ("Color") for the following "Code" combinations (Code = "A" & "B", Code = "B" & "C", Code = "A" & "C").
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From user **duckmayr** in the comments:

```
df %>% group_by(Code, Color) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(Value)) %>% tidyr::spread(Color, Sum, fill = 0)
```

This worked perfectly for my purposes.